# DB2 equivalent to SQL Server's SYSJOBS

Tags: sql-server, db2

I am a DB2 Novice and really need some help or pointers in the right direction. I need to capture the following fields (or similar) in DB2, that I can capture in SQL Server with the following SQL code,

```
select 
       jobs.name
       ,jstep.step_name
       ,jstep.command
from sysjobs jobs 
inner join sysjobsteps jstep on jstep.job_id = jobs.job_id
where jobs.name = 'some_job_name'
```

Surely, there's something similar for DB2. But, I just can't seem to find it or google the right combinations of key words. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: check this thread http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1654380-Find-DB2-job-name-from-system-tables

Comment: The answer depends on the DB2 version and platform you're using, as well as on the origin of the jobs you're trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 uses `Administrative Task Scheduler` (ATS). The view you need is `SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_LIST`. On a side note, the status of each task is in `SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_STATUS`.

HTH.